# Access nested JSON elements in Angular2 Service

Tags: json, angular

I have created an app with dynamic forms as explained in this tutorial: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html

Now I want to load the questions from a json file on a server instead of hard coded questions.

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
 "ventureReason":[
  {
"label": "Venture Reason",
"controlType": "dropdown",
"options": [
  {
    "key": "solid",
    "value": "Solid"
  },
  {
    "key": "great",
    "value": "Great"
  }
]
 }
],
"blablabla": [
{
  "label": "Blablabla",
  "controlType": "textbox",
  "options": [
  ]
}
]
}
```

In the `QuestionService` I want to build the questions based on value of `controlType`. But `item.controlType` always returns undefined. `data` contains the whole json file.

```
export class QuestionService {

questionUrl:string = `db`;
data:any;
questions : QuestionBase<any>[] = [];

constructor(
    private http: HttpService
){}

getQuestions() {
    return this.http.get(this.questionUrl)
    .map(res => [res.json()])
    .map(data => {
        this.data = data;
        return this.buildQuestions(data);
    })
}

buildQuestions(data) {
console.log("data: "+ JSON.stringify(data));  //whole json file
    let questions = [];
    data.forEach((item: QuestionGroup) => {
        console.log("item: " + JSON.stringify(item)); //whole json file
        console.log("item: " + JSON.stringify(item.controlType));  //undefined
        if (item.controlType == 'dropdown') {
            item.controlType = 'dropdown';
            questions.push(new DropdownQuestion(item));
        }
        else if (item.controlType == 'textbox') {
            item.controlType = 'textbox';
            questions.push(new TextboxQuestion(item));
        }
    });
    return questions;
}
```

}

How could I acces the `controlType` to build the questions?

Comment: Which part of your entire JSON object `item: QuestionGroup` should represent? I'm asking because both `console.log("data: "+ JSON.stringify(data));` and `console.log("item: " + JSON.stringify(item));` result in printing the whole json file (like you mentioned in your comments).

Comment: one item should be `ventureReason` and the other `blablabla`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the JSON object you've posted, you need to do this:

```
    data.forEach((questionGroup: QuestionGroup) => {
       questionGroup.forEach((item: any) => { 
       //you can replace 'any' with the appropriate class that represents 'item'
          //access item properties, like controlType
          console.log(item.controlType);
       });
    });
```

Comment: now the console.log of item isn't called at all but the console.log on data is executed 2 times

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the item's value is an array of objects. Maybe I'm mistaken, but I think `item[0].controlType` should return the result for which you're looking.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, when you look closely at your JSON, your data you want to access is inside an array `ventureReason`. You want the content of that array, so make a slight change to your mapping, and it should be all good!

```
.map(res => res.json().ventureReason) // extract the data from the array
```

so your `item.controlType` was undefined, since there was no property, since your single`item` actually contained only the property `ventureReason` and the whole array.

Here's

### [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/5tPOdZIBmfdTNRDDOpRG)

Comment: How did it go with these answers, did any of them solve your issue? :)